# Manually set weights in tensor flow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have built a neural network with custom layers.
The network has a number of trainable weights and biases:

```
<tf.Variable 'model/conv1/weight:0' shape=(5, 32) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/conv1/weight_1:0' shape=(32, 16) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/conv1/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/conv1/bias_1:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32_ref>
...
<tf.Variable 'model/finalConv/weight:0' shape=(68, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/finalConv/weight_1:0' shape=(128, 128) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/finalConv/weight_2:0' shape=(128, 55000) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/finalConv/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/finalConv/bias_1:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'model/finalConv/bias_2:0' shape=(55000,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

I have trained the neural network yielding good results in testing. I added an exporting method to my model, that exports the weights and biases in a numpy- format.
However, when I initialise a new model and import the weights I only get random results (even with the same data that yielded good results in the previous testing).

I am guessing, that the weights are not properly loaded into the model. This is what the layer object looks like and how I am importing and exporting the weights and biases:

```
class Layer(object):
    def __init__(self, layer_sizes, features, keep_prob=None):
        self.W = [weight_variable(shape=[layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i + 1]]) for i in range(len(layer_sizes) - 1)]
        self.B = [bias_variable(shape=[layer_sizes[i + 1]]) for i in range(len(layer_sizes) - 1)]
        self.do_something = DoingSomething(self.W, self.B, features, keep_prob)

    def export_weights_and_biases(self):
        """Export weights and biases of current layer."""
        return self.W, self.B

    def import_weights_and_biases(self, weights, biases):
        """Import weights and biases for current layer."""
        self.W = weights
        self.B = biases
```

When trying to load the trained model, I will then build the architecture (i.e. the graph), initialize the weights and biases and then attempt to load the parameters from the trained model as such:

```
Layer.import_weights_and_biases(saved_weights, saved_biases)
```

Followed by running the session with the testing data from training...

Does that actually update the variables in the graph? I feel like it does not end up in the right place and the model still has all the randomly initialised values...

Any help is much appreciated. Still struggling a bit with the concepts of tensor flow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For all of those of you who stumble across my question because I'm trying to save a model to the disk during training: There is an easier way! You can use tensor flow's own save module, even for custom models and layers. Refer to [this](https://www.easy-tensorflow.com/tf-tutorials/basics/save-and-restore) very helpful and easy to use guide.

Out of curiosity I would still like to know how to change the variables in a graph manually however, my question is therefor still unanswered....